# How I make this For Loop faster for my DataTable to Excel export?

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop, datatable

Im currently exporting my DataTable to an Excel File and for that I've got that loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < newsletter.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < newsletter.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (j == 2)
                    {
                        //exrngKopf = oWS.get_Range("A1", "A11");
                        oWS.Hyperlinks.Add(oWS.UsedRange.Item[i + 1, j + 1], newsletter.Rows[i][j + 8].ToString(), "", "", newsletter.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                        //MessageBox.Show("2");

                        j++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        oWS.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = newsletter.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                    }



                }
            }
```

**Note:** The `j == 2` is the part where it is an Hyperlink and thats why I add this difference to avoid Crashes.

And that Code is working and he is making the Excel Sheet correct, but the DataTable has like more then 10.000 data, so it works after 30 minute of Loading, someone an Idea how to make it faster ?

Comment: Is this using the Microsoft Interop libraries to work with Excel?

Comment: how fast do you expect this code to run? what type of system are you executing it on?